# Generalizing macros with LaTeX3

Tags: labels, xparse

I'm trying to increase my LaTeX3-fu, but I'm getting an error about encountering printed output before the document begins.

I'm trying to generalize [How to get the section title by section number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76078/).

I also understand that LaTeX3's big punch is to (mostly) do away with `\expandafter`, but I don't know the equivalent syntax if there is a one-to-one relationship.  (I'm really just trying to learn, here :-).)

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

% Macro to insert labels at the end of other macros
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\labelize}{mm}{
  % Automatically inserts a label of the form \label{#2:\the#1}for
  % referencing after every #1

  % For example:
  % \labelize{section}{auto-section}
  % ...
  % \begin{document}
  % \section{something}
  % -->\label{auto-section:1}
  % \section{something else}
  % -->\label{auto-section:2}
  % \end{document}


  % #1 : Macro to labelize
  % #2 : Prefix for label

  % Store the old macro
  \let\expandafter\csname old#1\endcsname\expandafter\csname #1\endcsname

  % Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76078/
               % how-to-get-the-section-title-by-section-number
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname #1\endcsname[2]{
    \ifx##1\relax
      \csname old#1\endcsname{##2}
    \else
      \csname old#1\endcsname[##1]{##2}
    \fi
    \label{#2:\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\labelize{section}{auto@section}

\begin{document}
Hi
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should know that `\section` takes *no* argument. It's not clear what the `\labelize` command should do. And, most importantly, you're trying to redefine `\expandafter`; at least switch the positions of `\renewcommand` and `\expandafter`; `\expandafter\csname` is a (minor) mistake, too.

Comment: @egreg ? but `section{argument here?}`?  How then does the more explicit case (linked) work?  I tried to model it exactly.

Comment: Well, I'd say that Werner's answer is not the best LaTeX programming I've ever seen. Can you please state clearly what `\labelize` is supposed to do?

Comment: @egreg See my edit, I incorporated your notes from your first comment, although I'm still unsure of what you mean by "`\section` takes no arguments"... it at least seems to as an end-user.

Comment: @egreg Do you think I need to `\expandafter` to hop over `\let` until the control sequences `\csname ... \endcsname` resolve?

Comment: `\let\expandafter\csname...\endcsname` defines `\expandafter` to mean `\csname`, which is not what you want.  Presumably, `\expandafter\let\csname...\endcsname` is wanted.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch One of my many careless mistakes.  I noticed the difference as I was going through egreg's answer and facepalm'd myself.  Right, it was *absolutely* not what I meant, but it was *absolutely* what I told TeX to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what `xparse` and LaTeX3 has to do with this. You have almost all your `\expandafter` commands in the wrong place.

This works, but you lose the ability of using `\section*`.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Macro to insert labels at the end of other macros
\newcommand{\labelize}[2]{%
  % Automatically inserts a label of the form \label{#2:\the#1}for
  % referencing after every #1
  % For example:
  % \labelize{section}{auto-section}
  % ...
  % \begin{document}
  % \section{something}
  % -->\label{auto-section:1}
  % \section{something else}
  % -->\label{auto-section:2}
  % \end{document}
  % #1 : Macro to labelize
  % #2 : Prefix for label
  % Store the old macro
  \expandafter\let\csname old#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
  % Adapted from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76078/
               % how-to-get-the-section-title-by-section-number
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname #1\endcsname[2][]{
    \if\relax\detokenize{##1}\relax
      \csname old#1\endcsname{##2}%
    \else
      \csname old#1\endcsname[##1]{##2}%
    \fi
    \label{#2: \csname the#1\endcsname}%
  }
}

\labelize{section}{auto@section}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
Hi

\ref{auto@section:1}
\end{document}
```

Of course using `\ref{auto@section:1}` is pointless, but if the automatically generated label is to be used via some macro, then it can be useful.

Here's a LaTeX3 version that allows for `\section*` as well as the optional argument. Note, however, that the first argument to `\labelize` should be the command (with the backslash). It would be possible to use the same syntax as before, but I believe this is clearer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Macro to insert labels at the end of other macros
\NewDocumentCommand{\labelize}{mm}
 {
  \sean_labelize:Nn #1 { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \sean_labelize:Nn #1 #2
 {
  \cs_set_eq:cN { original_ \cs_to_str:N #1 } #1
  \RenewDocumentCommand #1 { som }
   {
    \IfBooleanTF{##1}
     {
      \use:c { original_ \cs_to_str:N #1 }*{##3}
     }
     {
      \IfNoValueTF{##2}
       {
        \use:c { original_ \cs_to_str:N #1 } {##3}
       }
       {
        \use:c { original_ \cs_to_str:N #1 } [##2]{##3}
       }
      \label{#2: \use:c{the\cs_to_str:N #1} }%
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\labelize{\section}{auto@section}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
Hi

\ref{auto@section:1}

\section*{Star}

Hi
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works like a charm, but it isn't magic.  I've got a date with the library's copy of the TeXbook this Tuesday; I've yet to read it so I'm not surprised about my own misuse and abuse of `\expandafter`.  I'll have to study the syntax you've used, but I *was* looking for a LaTeX3 version, hence the tag.  The reference will be automatically used in the [breadcrumbs question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122792).